# Update and delete at the same time Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table of this kind

**Table of items with price under 100**

| Prod_ID | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 67 |
| 3 | 89 |
| 4 | 91 |
| 5 | 23 |
| 6 | 98 |

Now I Want to write PostgresSQL command to update the price of each item increasing it by $10 and want to delete all the items with price more than $100

After the query, the table should be:

| Prod_ID | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 |
| 2 | 77 |
| 3 | 99 |
| 5 | 33 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update` first and then `delete`.

```
UPDATE your_table_name set PRICE=PRICE + 10;
DELETE FROM your_table_name  WHERE PRICE > 100;
```